# Eslint and Typescript complain about a variable declared in two different files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I run into a quite basic configuration problem with Typescript and ESLint. I have a variable named the same in two different .ts files and Typescript complains about them for being defined twice:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'myVariable'.ts(2451)
myfile.spec.ts(5, 15): 'myVariable' was also declared here.
```

What should I configure to avoid such errors to come up in VSCode ?

This variable is a top-level variable, it's not inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. Use modules so that top-level declarations aren't globals, they're scoped to the module instead. (This would mean there would be two of them, each separate from the other, one for each module.)
2. Don't declare the variable twice, if you really want it to be a shared global. Declare it in one file and use it in the other.
3. Change both declarations to use `var` rather than `let`/`const` (the "block-scoped" part of the error message tells us you're using `let` or `const`). You can redeclare `var` globals.

I'd strongly recommend #1. Globals are best avoided whenever possible, and in modern environments it's almost always possible.

Comment: It's also the case for import statements like
const { some-import } = require('some-package');

What can I do about them ?

Comment: Those shouldn't be global. If you're using CommonJS modules (`require`), that code is effectively running within an inline-invoked function expression, so that constant is local to the module's scope (this is basically #1 above). It sounds like the `module` setting in `tsconfig.json` is set incorrectly.

Comment: I indeed had modified my tsconfig.json to target esnext by error, and I refactor my code anyway to factorize to a generic helper. I'm using a module now, so no warning anymore, thanks for these hints.

Comment: @ThéoLavaux - Great! Glad that helped! FWIW, I'd author in ESM (`import`/`export`) rather than CommonJS (`require` `exports`), since that's the now-standard syntax, and have the tools convert / bundle it as necessary for your target environments. (And I don't just say that because I go into the details of ESM syntax in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. :-D But...well...I do go into it, so if you're interested, links in my profile.)